# Example files in d3-graphviz download won't run (necessary files seem to be missing)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphviz

I'm very new to Javascript, Graphviz, and D3, and I'm having issues setting up D3-graphviz. I downloaded the latest release on Github, but none of the html files in the "example" folder will run when I open them in my browser.

When I looked at the script src lines at the beginning of the files (see below), they referenced "node_modules" and "build" files that I didn't have. I tried creating the node_modules folder and adding d3.js and graphviz.js, but I don't seem to have a d3-graphviz.js file to put in a build folder.

I also tried creating html files with script src lines similar to the ones in the online demos, but this didn't work either.

The original script src lines (when I tried to run the example files unedited):

```
<script src="../node_modules/d3/dist/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/viz.js/viz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
```

and the alternate ones I also tried:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@2.6.1/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
```

Both times, when I go to open the html file in Google Chrome or Safari, it just opens a blank page. However, when I follow the demos in the readme (e.g. [here](https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/4acffdb3afbc4f71b448a210b5060bca)), they work just fine. I can also successfully generate static graphs using just graphviz and Terminal.

I'm wondering if I am missing a step in the setup process, or missing a dependency (other than graphviz and d3) that I should download? I can't find any other questions about struggling with just showing an animation at all, so I would appreciate any advice :)

Comment: `npm install` probably :)

Comment: Update: I solved it, and here's how. I used Gordon's comment as a jumping-off point and went to install npm, which I didn't have; when I did that, I realized I didn't have Node.js, so I installed both. It turned out the key dependency I was missing was rollup; once I installed that, and then re-installed all the other dependencies, it worked. I still had to rewrite the file paths, but at least I had the files they pointed to so I was able to do that.

Comment: That's great, thanks for following up. Sometimes it's hard to know where to start. Running the command `npm install` in the project directory should install all the dependencies in the `node_modules` subdirectory but I haven't looked closely at d3-graphviz. Too bad people think this question isn't on topic - it's an important prerequisite for programming in javascript.

Comment: There may be some mistake in your html file.
I'm working on the same stack you're working on.
For me, its working fine. Please provide some additional source code.